# how to show automatically updated sever time and date on web page

Tags: php, time, server

I am working on a project that this already works on but I am unable to replicate it on a new build(I was working on the instructions to share with others). The below script automatically calls the timeauto.php file and displays the servers time and date on the web page, this is for a bell system which makes it handy to see what the server time actually is. I have been able to replicate it as far as it works when accessed from the server but when a user looks at the page the time and date do not display. Any help would be appreciated.

Section from main page

```
    <body>
    <!––Automatically updates server time on webpage from timeauto.php file-->
    <h3></h3>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        setInterval(function(){   
        $("h3").load("timeauto.php");
        }, 1000);
    });
    </script>
<?php
```

Code in the timeauto.php file

```
<?php
//Automatically updates server time on webpage
echo "Time from bell server: ";
echo "<br>";
echo date("d-m-Y h:i:sa");
```

?>

Comment: have a look in the developer tools, F12, console for errors. be sure to have included jquery before using it.

Comment: Thanks for that, it apears that it is caching on the one that is not working and I must have found a way to turn it of in apache for the one that is working. More googling required.

Comment: for a simple way, loading the timeauto.php every time new, try ... var lnRandom = Math.random(); $("h3").load("timeauto.php?something="+ lnRandom); ...

Comment: I worked out what the issue was and although I had restarted the server I had missed restarted the user side computer which was the issue, sometimes its the simple things that can catch you out. Thanks for the help.